# How to have multiple plots in a single frame?

Tags: plotting

I want to plot more than one plot in a single frame for the following syntax.
I'm not getting how to do it.
Kindly guide me.

````
xi = 0.5;
Plot[Im[y], {k, 0, 100}, PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> {Red, Thick}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"k", 
   "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(Ω\), \(i\)]\)"}, Frame -> True,
  FrameStyle -> Thick, 
 PlotLegends -> {"k", 
   "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(Ω\), \(i\)]\)"}]

xi = 10;
Plot[Im[y], {k, 0, 100}, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotStyle -> {Black, Dashed, Thick}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"k", 
   "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(Ω\), \(i\)]\)"}, Frame -> True,
  FrameStyle -> Thick, 
 PlotLegends -> {"k", 
   "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(Ω\), \(i\)]\)"}]

xi = 1000;
Plot[Im[y], {k, 0, 100}, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotStyle -> {Blue, Thick, Dashed}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"k", 
   "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(Ω\), \(i\)]\)"}, Frame -> True,
  FrameStyle -> Thick, 
 PlotLegends -> {"k", 
   "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(Ω\), \(i\)]\)"}]
```
````

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Show` to combine multiple plots:

```
plot1 = Plot[Sin[3 x], {x, -Pi, Pi}, PlotStyle -> Dashed]
```

and

```
plot2 = Plot[Sin[2 x]*Cos[x], {x, -Pi, Pi}, PlotStyle -> Red]
```

then

```
Show[{plot1, plot2}]
```

delivers:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Since you didn't provide `y` I made one up. You can combine them all into a single `Plot` and use `Directive`. I also took the liberty of changing `AxesLabel` to `FrameLabel` and disabling `RotateLabel` and adding the legends.

```
y = k^3/2 + I Log[k + 1]/Sqrt[xi];

Plot[{Im[y] /. {xi -> .5}, Im[y] /. xi -> 10, 
 Im[y] /. xi -> 1000}, {k, 0, 100},
 PlotRange -> All,
 PlotStyle -> {
   Directive[Red, Thick],
   Directive[Black, Dashed, Thick],
   Directive[Blue, Thick, Dashed]
 },
 Frame -> True,
 FrameStyle -> Thick,
 PlotLegends -> {"k for \[Xi] == 0.5", "k for \[Xi] == 10", "k for \[Xi] == 1000"},
 FrameLabel -> {"k", "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[CapitalOmega]\), \(i\)]\)"}, 
 RotateLabel -> False]
```

[image: multiple plots with styles frame and legend]

Comment: Sir, I tried to add the Framelevel in the 3d plot but it shows error. How can I get the Framelevel in 3d plot. AxesLevel and PlotLegends also does not get execute properly. It shows the level for x axis but does not show the level for y axis.    Plot3D[Im[y], {xi, 0.1, 10}, {k, 10, 100}, PlotRange -> All, 
 BoundaryStyle -> Directive[Red, Thick], 
 PlotLegends -> {"\[Xi]", "k"}, AspectRatio -> 0.5]

Comment: FrameLevel? I assume you mean `FrameLabel`. This is not an option for `Plot3D` but you should use `AxesLabel->{xi,k,Subscript[Ω,i]}` . Also don't use `AspectRatio` in `Plot3D`, use `BoxRatios` instead.

Comment: Sir, in Plot3D it does not show me the PlotLegends properly. It only shows the first parameter passed, the other two parameter gets hidden.I'm using Plot3D[Im[y], {xi, 0.1, 10}, {k, 10, 100}, PlotRange -> All, 
 BoundaryStyle -> Directive[Red, Thick], 
 AxesLabel -> {\[Xi], k, Subscript[\[CapitalOmega], i]}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"\[Xi]", "k", 
   "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[CapitalOmega]\), \(i\)]\)"}, Mesh -> {{0}},
  BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}].When I run this code I get only Xi but not the other two.

Comment: @RahulChakraborty Plot3D? That's a different question altogether.

Comment: No Sir, same topic continuing, so far all queries related to plot3d only I have asked.